# How do you paginate sub-queries in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have a CakePHP 3 application which has 2 models, `Urls` and `Downloads`. The models are associated such that a URL may have multiple downloads (`Urls hasMany Downloads` in Cake terminology).

When I do a query such as this it will return 1 row from the `Urls` table and all of the associated `Downloads`:

```
// This is in a view() method
$query = $this->Urls->find()->contain(['Downloads' => ['sort' => ['Downloads.created' => 'DESC'] ] ])->where(['id' => $id]);
```

I want to paginate the list of `Downloads` but can't see how to do this. I've taken a look at https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html but the only thing I could find which I tried was:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
}

// In my view() method
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => ['Downloads']
];

$query = $this->Urls->find()->contain(['Downloads' => ['sort' => ['Downloads.created' => 'DESC'] ] ])->where(['id' => $id])->paginate();
```

But it just errors saying 
**Unknown method "paginate"**

Comment: You may want to have a closer look at the docs again, the `paginate()` method isn't a method of the table class.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are showing just one Url you could do two queries.

one query to retrieve the url (without the downloads)

```
$url = $this->Urls->get($id);
```

the second one to retrieve (and paginate!) the dowloads

```
$downloads = $this->Urls->Downloads->find()
    ->sort(['created' => 'DESC'])
    ->where(['url_id' => $id]);

$downloads = $this->paginate($downloads)
```

Comment: I'm really looking to do it all in 1 query, since the point of being able to use `contain` is that you *don't* have to do separate queries. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: cake will eventually do two distinct queries to retrieve the data. So I don't see the point

Answer (score 0):

Since Downloads belongs to Urls, you could Do the opposite, like this:

```
$downloads = $this->Urls->Downloads->find()
    ->contain('Urls')
    ->where(['url_id' => $id])
    ->order(['created' => 'DESC']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because `paginate()` is not a method of the table class and you are calling it on the table object, so it is unknown. You need to call it on the Controller object:-

```
$this->paginate();
```

As `paginate` is a controller method, it can't be called as part of the query for retrieving the `Url` as you are trying in your example. This means that you need to perform two queries, but this is what CakePHP would have down if you'd contained the downloads. For example:-

```
$this->Urls->get($id, ['contain' => 'Downloads']);
```

This essentially results in the following two queries as it can't be done in SQL using a `JOIN`:-

```
$this->Urls->get($id);
$this->Urls->Downloads->find('all')->where(['url_id' => $id])->all();
```

So, you need get the `Url` first:-

```
$url = $this->Urls->get($id);
```

And then to paginate the downloads you want to pass the find query for the downloads into your paginate method:-

```
$query = $this->Urls->Downloads->find()
    ->sort(['created' => 'DESC'])
    ->where(['url_id' => $id]);
$downloads = $this->paginate($query);
```