# How to sort on fields from contained associations when using the paginator?

Tags: sorting, cakephp, pagination, contains, cakephp-3.x

How to use CakePHP to pagination on a paginated query? Data it's ok, but not working sort links....

In my controller:

```
 $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Slaves.Devices','Measurements','AlarmTypes.FunctionTypes.Units'],
        'maxLimit'=>50
    ];

    $alarms=$this->AlarmGenerates->find()
            ->select([
                'Slaves.name',
                'Devices.name',
                'AlarmTypes.nazwa',
                'FunctionTypes.name',
                'Measurements.value',
                'AlarmTypes.max_value',
                'AlarmTypes.min_value',
                'Units.name',
                'AlarmGenerates.created'
                ])
            ->contain(['Slaves.Devices','Measurements','AlarmTypes.FunctionTypes.Units']);
    $alarmyAll=$this->paginate($alarms);
```

In template:

```
<th><?=$this->Paginator->sort('slave.device.name','Obiekt')?></th>
<th><?=$this->Paginator->sort('alarm_type.nazwa','Nazwa Alarmu')?></th>
<th><?=$this->Paginator->sort('name',null,['model'=>'FunctionTypes'])?></th>
<th><?=$this->Paginator->sort('measurement.value','Wartość',['model'=>'Measurement'])?></th>
 <th><?=$this->Paginator->sort('alarm_type.max_value','Dopuszczalny przedzial')?></th>
 <th><?=$this->Paginator->sort('created','Czas wystąpienia')?></th>
```

Pleas help...

Comment: I asked this recently, and the answer is very unclear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490930/how-do-you-paginate-sub-queries-in-cakephp-3 If anyone knows I'd be very interested to know how to do this too.

Comment: Please be more specific. What **exactly** does not work with the sort links?

Comment: If I click on the link to sort the column containing the data from the association, then the page is reloaded but the data is not sorted. And if I click on a link that does not contain data from the association then it sorts and will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the columns that you want to be able to sort by to the paginate's whitelist:-

```
public $paginate = [
    'contain' => ['Slaves.Devices', 'Measurements', 'AlarmTypes.FunctionTypes.Units'],
    'maxLimit' => 50,
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        'slave.device.name',
        'alarm_type.nazwa',
        'name',
        'measurement.value',
        'alarm_type.max_value',
        'created'
    ]
];
```

If you need to be able to sort on any columns from associated data then you need to define the columns in the `sortWhitelist` as mentioned in the [official docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#control-which-fields-used-for-ordering).

> This option is required when you want to sort on any associated data, or computed fields that may be part of your pagination query